# Replace All 'src'-attributes in HTML with 'data-src' attributes in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I'm creating an application which receives HTML E-Mails.

Due to security concerns we would like to disable automatically loading images in those E-Mails.

The game plan:

1. Sanitization
2. Replace all `src` attributes in IMG tags with `data-src` attributes (using the same value) in PHP
3. Add Button to Frontend
4. On Click change `data-src` attribute back to `img` and allow the browser to allow to load the images.

My problem now:
I can write a basic Regex to replace the `src` attribute in a simple `<img src="abc.jpg" />` but I have no idea how to replace `src` with `data-src` in more complex and even potentially malformed html.

Am I thinking to complex? Is there an easy solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you grab your HTML as a string and then run: `str_replace('src', 'data-src', $My_HTML)` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the problematic case you would have

```
src=
```

of course, some whitespaces can be before or after the =. One might be inclined to ignore instances between apostrophes and quotes, but you cannot save then against sophisticated attacks, such as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img = '<img src="foo">';
    document.body.innerHTML += img;
</script>
```

The best would be to parse the HTML in a browser-like environment and run

```
document.querySelectorAll("img[src]").length
```

after page load. If it's 0, then you do not have `src`. However, you might still have the danger of having some CSS file linked into the HTML with a `background-image` property defined.

So, I would implement a regular expression that protects against `src=` and `background-image:` as well (potentially with whitespaces). The best is if Javascript is not allowed to run at all and no outside-sources are allowed for CSS either.